# PhpStorm - Rebuild project using Local History (after deleting all project files)?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I did something profoundly stupid today. I used `rm` command incorrectly and deleted all my website files.

I just looked in PhpStorm `local history` and I see all my lost files. That was quite the relief. But how can I use this local history to basically restore the project and recreate the actual folder structure that was lost?

Under my actual site folder `/Library/Webserver/Documents/site` there is nothing but using a recovery program I see an `.idea` folder and contents.

Also, I have remote version of the site that has same files minus a bunch of new files I made recently. All these new files are visible in `Local History` and clicking on a file does indeed show me the code. So maybe I copy all remote files over and just copy text from Local History to manually create all the deleted files? That would be plan B, since I am hoping Local History can perform some magic and actually restore my project...

Ideas?

Comment: Wow - just read here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/01/using-local-history-to-restore-deleted-files/ Absolutely incredible. I am now recreating my entire project thanks to this insanely amazing feature of PHPStorm!

Comment: [Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/local-history.html) will have modified files + those deleted from within the IDE (not sure on the 2nd one for 100% though; limit on file size). Internally they must be stored as a bunch of diff/patch files. I'd suggest to recover whatever is possible from Local History first, save those files elsewhere and then merge with remote once you download them. I've never used it for such crucial recovery, only accidental deletion/unwanted modification (e.g. rollback to a version from 1 hour ago).

Comment: I have no idea how Local History works but I just checked the directory structure as restored by PHPStorm and it is 2.8GB. So somehow this magical feature has just saved the day. Unreal that this feature exists and that it can work this sort of miracle. I want to buy that whole company a round of drinks!